# Installing GCC with all dependencies

Tags: linux, gcc, debian

I'm trying to install GCC in my Debian but when I execute `./contrib/download_prerequisites` command, I receive a "Forbidden" error, indicating that I'm not allowed to retrieve one or more packages from its resources due to proxy restrictions.

I'm not able to bypass proxy neither contact administrator in order to get permission. So, I'd like to download a complete set of GCC packages, if available. Unfortunately my Linux is quite spartan and apt-get and aptitude very often don't work due to dependencies issues. So, a tar-gz/bz approach would be fine.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: for a onetime thing this is overkill, but you could set up a partial repository mirror on a usb disk with debpartial-mirror

Comment: what do you mean by "dependency issues" when working with `apt`? even if your system is *spartan*, i'd recommend installing all the *required* dependencies (you can configure `aptitude` to not install *recommended/suggested* packages, which should keep your system at a minimum)

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to setup aptitude to install all the required dependencies. Fortunatelly, these resources weren't blocked by proxy's firewall, and all them could be downloaded. Thanks to aptitude.